# Unable to start telnet session from java

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, telnet

I am currently working on a Java Applet which is supposed to start a telnet session via command line. My current approach is to run:

```
String connectionString = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /k \"telnet\"";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(connectionString);
```

When I execute this, cmd.exe opens but displays "telnet is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

I do have telnet set up, there is no problem opening a cmd window and executing telnet there. I also tried to run the above snippet with other programs (rasdial, jarsigner) and it perfectly works.

Why would the cmd.exe not recognize telnet when started from java? Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using 32-bit JVM ?

Comment: Eclipse config showing: "sun.arch.data.model=32" - so, apparently, yes. Does that make a difference?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/564125/java/java/Launching-telnet-java-program-fails) post, yes !

Comment: Please refer to my answer below, in case you use [Apache Commons Net API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net//index.html).

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the problem. But as I try to run this from an applet, this seems pretty frustrating as I would have to ensure every client is having the proper JVM installed... 
Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JVM is 32-bit on a Windows 7 system, then according to [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/564125/java/java/Launching-telnet-java-program-fails) post

*`...on a 64-bit Windows 7 system, telnet only works when launched from a 64-bit application....`*

You can try [Apache Commons Net API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net//index.html) which support telnet protocol. You can refer [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net//examples/telnet/TelnetClientExample.java) sample example. You can also refer [this](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=40) reference guide.